# Android DatePicker onDateChaged fires for wrong date

Tags: android, datepicker

*Disclaimer: The title should be clear enough, this is not a question on `DatePicker` being fired twice, but being fired for a previous value.*

I don't know how this is even possible..

The related code from fragment `onCreateView` :

```
Log.d("PaginationFragment#", "setting the dateDepartureInit to : " + dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.YEAR));
dateDeparture.init(dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateDepartureInit.get(Calendar.DATE), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.set(i, i2, i3);

                Log.d("PaginationFragment#", "onFormDateEvent : " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                listener.onFormDateEvent(CriterionName.DATE_DEPARTURE, c, iPosition);

            }
        });
```

the output:

```
03-04 .. 11909-11909/...app D/PaginationFragment#﹕ setting the dateDepartureInit to : 2016
03-04 .. 11909-11909/...app D/PaginationFragment#﹕ onFormDateEvent : 2015
```

As you can see in the logs, a date (in *2016*) used to init the `DatePicker`, 
then the event fires but with the previous value (*2015*).

**It is important to note:**

- `dateDepartureInit` is of type `Calendar`.
- the fragment is used in a `ViewPager`

**EDIT:**

Logging some more, I can see that the date changed event is fired after the completion of `onCreateView` ..

```
03-05 11:03:05.384    3003-3003/org.intracode.shoppingalertsystem.app D/PaginationFragment#﹕ start of onCreateView
03-05 11:03:05.390    3003-3003/org.intracode.shoppingalertsystem.app D/PaginationFragment#﹕ end of onCreateView
03-05 11:03:05.394    3003-3003/org.intracode.shoppingalertsystem.app 
D/PaginationFragment#﹕ onDateChanged fired!
```

Comment: where is *init* being used twice? is `dateDepartureInit` a `Calendar`?

Comment: updated: pls ignore what I said about the calling twice.. (removed from the question)

Comment: @Blackbelt how is this a dupe of the other one?! there are two separate issues here obviously! one is the wrong value and the other is the extra event!